# Not allowed to load local resource: file:///D

Tags: javascript, html

I am running this HTML program from visual studio using live-server from terminal

```
cd<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Developer Skills & Editor Setup</title>
    <style>
      body {
        height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        background: linear-gradient(to top left, #28b487, #7dd56f);
      }
      h1 {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 50px;
        line-height: 1.3;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Developer Skills & Editor Setup</h1>
    <script src="D:\JAVASCRIPT\complete-javascript-course-master\complete-javascript-course-master\03-Developer-Skills\starter\script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

put I get an error in chrome console :

Not allowed to load local resource: file:///D:/JAVASCRIPT/...

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xHdc.png)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oTVQ.png)
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1rp9.png)

Comment: You should use relative paths in your dependencies. Simply change src to `script.js`

Answer (score 1):

you can't use local resources intel chrome allow you it's because of  security reasons Chrome will not load local files by default. so you need to use this method to make google load your local resources :
(https://kb.madcapsoftware.com/Content/Misc/GEN1011Z_-_Loading_local_files_in_Google_Chrome.htm)